# Content edit links?

Tags: views, 8, nodes, navigation

I'm new to Drupal 8 and can't figure out a way to show the edit contextual links for content displayed through the Views module. This was simple in Drupal 7, but in Drupal 8, a view only shows the links for editing; there are no edit or quickedit links for the content.

It does seem to work with nodes and taxonomy terms, but not custom blocks.

Comment: Try to add operations field in view. It will provide edit,delete operations links in drop down.

Comment: Does not work since I'm not using fields.

Comment: Added answer may be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add show content and teaser/full view like below.

[image]

Goto page and it will show links.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work with custom blocks. Nodes and taxonomy terms work.

Comment: Is there any possibility to change with fields rather than showing full/default mode?

Comment: No, I will have to change the content to nodes instead of blocks.